# Plotting animations to Jupyter Notebook: why does HTML(animator.to_html()) not work when called in an inner scope (i.e in a function)?

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, jupyter-notebook

The following source shows how to plot animations inline to Jupyter Notebook (with `matplotlib` of course):

http://louistiao.me/posts/notebooks/embedding-matplotlib-animations-in-jupyter-as-interactive-javascript-widgets/

Running the code, it works when I run it directly in a cell (i.e like a script):

```
from matplotlib import animation, rc
from IPython.display import HTML

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.set_xlim((0, 2))
ax.set_ylim((-2, 2))

line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)

def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
    return (line,)

def animate(i):
    x = np.linspace(0, 2, 1000)
    y = np.sin(2 * np.pi * (x - 0.01 * i))
    line.set_data(x, y)
    return (line,)

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                               frames=100, interval=20, 
                               blit=True)

#HTML(anim.to_html5_video())
HTML(anim.to_jshtml())
```

However, when I try to run this within a function, it does not plot an inline figure:

```
from matplotlib import animation, rc
from IPython.display import HTML


def plot_anim_funct():
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    ax.set_xlim((0, 2))
    ax.set_ylim((-2, 2))

    line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)

    def init():
        line.set_data([], [])
        return (line,)

    def animate(i):
        x = np.linspace(0, 2, 1000)
        y = np.sin(2 * np.pi * (x - 0.01 * i))
        line.set_data(x, y)
        return (line,)

    anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                                   frames=100, interval=20, 
                                   blit=True)

    #HTML(anim.to_html5_video())
    HTML(anim.to_jshtml())

plot_anim_funct()
```

It doesn't plot anything actually (well there is a static non-animated figure, but that always shows up, I think from running `anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, frames=100, interval=20, blit=True)`.

Of course, returning the animator object from the function, and then running `HTML(anim.to_jshtml())` works as before.

Is there a way to get this working inside a function or do I just need to return the animator every time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HTML(..)` creates a html string from an object. If this is not the last line of the cell it will not be shown. To be on the safe side, you may use `IPython.display.display`

```
display(HTML(anim.to_jshtml()))
```

Complete working code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation, rc
from IPython.display import HTML, display


def plot_anim_funct():
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    ax.set_xlim((0, 2))
    ax.set_ylim((-2, 2))

    line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)

    def init():
        line.set_data([], [])
        return (line,)

    def animate(i):
        x = np.linspace(0, 2, 1000)
        y = np.sin(2 * np.pi * (x - 0.01 * i))
        line.set_data(x, y)
        return (line,)

    anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                                   frames=100, interval=20, 
                                   blit=True)


    display(HTML(anim.to_jshtml()))

plot_anim_funct()
```